# Why isn't sed's output stored with its multiple backslashes in bash?

Tags: bash, sed, output, backslash

I am trying to store the output of sed into a variable, however the output differs from what I expect.

My test is the following one

```
$ foo="this is (foo)"
$ x="$(sed 's/(/\\\\(/g' <<< $foo)"
```

The result expected is :

```
$ echo $x
this is \\(foo)
```

The result I get is :

```
$ echo $x
this is \(foo)
```

However, when I do not assign the output to a variable, then result is the expected one :

```
$ sed 's/(/\\\\(/g' <<< $foo
this is \\(foo)
```

**Why is the storage of my output failing?**

NOTE :

I also tried the following command lines which all ended to the same result :

```
$ x=`sed 's/(/\\\\(/g' <<< $foo`

$ x=$(sed 's/(/\\\\(/g' <<< $foo)

$ x=`echo $foo | sed 's/(/\\\\(/g'`

$ x=$(echo $foo | sed 's/(/\\\\(/g')
```

Comment: BTW, backticks will consume your literal backslashes, so for those (but not `$(...)`), you've got an additional failure mode.

Comment: This is not answering your question (hence a comment ;) ), but what I like to do for sed testing is `[vim]diff infile <(sed '...' infile)`.

Comment: That is in interesting way to do :)

Comment: Quote your variables (`"$x"`, not `$x`) unless you have a very specific reason not to and fully understand the behavior you are invoking by not doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't trust `echo`: The POSIX specification leaves enough leeway in its implementation that you can't trust its output to correctly represent the value at hand. Instead, use `printf`:

```
foo="this is (foo)"
x="$(sed 's/(/\\\\(/g' <<<"$foo")"
printf '%s\n' "$x"
```

...properly emits...

```
this is \\(foo)
```

---

From [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), emphasis added:

> The following operands shall be supported:
>
> *string*
>
> A string to be written to standard output. If the first operand is `-n`, or if **any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character,** the results are implementation-defined.

Similarly, from the APPLICATION USAGE section of that same document:

> It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.
>
> The `printf` utility can be used portably to emulate any of the traditional behaviors of the echo utility [...]

Comment: So no more `echo` for debugging I guess... Thanks! Is it normal then than the error output (`STDERR`) of other functions (such as `scp`) does not display the additional backslashes?

Comment: `scp` is a special case, because it runs remote filenames through a partial shell expansion pass on the remote end. That's not good practice, to put it mildly, but necessary to get wildcard expansion remotely without doing a bunch of extra work.

Comment: ...so, for *most* commands, that are implemented in better/saner ways than `scp`, that would be abnormal, but the specific case is a different issue.

Comment: BTW, re: debugging, use `set -x`, or `bash -x yourscript`; that'll give you your commands shell-quoted on stderr -- which is much more useful than `echo` anyhow; you can't tell the difference between `echo "foo bar"` and `echo foo bar`, and that difference is huge and important! You can also use something like `PS4=':$LINENO+'` with `set -x` to print the line number of each command as it's executed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this will definitely help me to debug faster!

Comment: (On a related note, `printf '%q'` is another useful tool to have in your arsenal -- with ksh or derivatives such as bash, it evaluates to its input quoted in such a way as to be `eval`-safe... though avoiding any cases where data is parsed as code in a shell is better than escaping -- with backslashes or otherwise -- to make that parsing safe, if one *does* need to do escaping, better to know how to do it right).